# While loop, IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Full code:

```
  public static String[] dirReduc(String[] arr) {


    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));


    for (int t = 0; t < list.size(); t++) {
        for (int q = t + 1; q < list.size() ; q++) {


        while (list.get(t).contains("NORTH") && list.get(q).contains("SOUTH") ||
                list.get(t).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(q).contains("NORTH") ||
                list.get(t).contains("WEST") && list.get(q).contains("EAST") ||
                list.get(t).contains("EAST") && list.get(q).contains("WEST"))



            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                for (int k = i + 1; k < list.size(); k++) {

                    if (list.get(i).contains("NORTH") && list.get(k).contains("SOUTH") ||
                        list.get(i).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(k).contains("NORTH") ||
                        list.get(i).contains("WEST") && list.get(k).contains("EAST") ||
                        list.get(i).contains("EAST") && list.get(k).contains("WEST")) {
                        list.remove(i);
                        list.remove(k - 1);
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Loops to remove works fine.

My question about while loop:

in while loop in this field:

```
 list.get(t).contains("WEST") && list.get(q).contains("EAST") ||
```

i've got: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Only one element remains in List.

As far as I could get: index q check element after last element in list and get OutOfBound.

How can I fix this?

In similar topics, I couldn't find clear answer, for my question, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Please provide the full code snippet to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have q equalling (t + 1) which would be out of bounds already so you must check if q is less than or equal to the list size to run the while loop to continue the program.

```
if (q <= list.size()) {
    // Your while loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not check whether list contains one or not before entering while loop like this because it is this case that is making to have the error.

```
  if(list.size() == 1)
     q=t
```

in your code like this:

```
for (int t = 0; t < list.size(); t++) {
        for (int q = t + 1; q < list.size() ; q++) {
          if(list.size() == 1)
             q=t;
        while (list.get(t).contains("NORTH") && list.get(q).contains("SOUTH") ||
                list.get(t).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(q).contains("NORTH") ||
                list.get(t).contains("WEST") && list.get(q).contains("EAST") ||
                list.get(t).contains("EAST") && list.get(q).contains("WEST"))
```

or avoid the while loop if list contains exactly one element.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue.

You need to check the index before using it on the list :

```
while (t < list.size() && q < list.size() &&  (list.get(t).contains("NORTH") && list.get(q).contains("SOUTH") ||
                list.get(t).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(q).contains("NORTH") ||
                list.get(t).contains("WEST") && list.get(q).contains("EAST") ||
                list.get(t).contains("EAST") && list.get(q).contains("WEST")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Should check not before loop, and loop itself.

Aftel while loop check conditions for break loop.

work like this:

```
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));


    for (int t = 0; t < list.size(); t++) {
        for (int q = t + 1; q < list.size(); q++) {
                while (list.get(t).contains("NORTH") && list.get(q).contains("SOUTH")
                       || list.get(t).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(q).contains("NORTH")
                       || list.get(t).contains("WEST") && list.get(q).contains("EAST")
                       || list.get(t).contains("EAST") && list.get(q).contains("WEST"))

                    if (q < list.size()) q = t;


                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    for (int k = i + 1; k < list.size(); k++) {

                        if (list.get(i).contains("NORTH") && list.get(k).contains("SOUTH")
                                || list.get(i).contains("SOUTH") && list.get(k).contains("NORTH")
                                || list.get(i).contains("WEST") && list.get(k).contains("EAST")
                                || list.get(i).contains("EAST") && list.get(k).contains("WEST")) {
                            list.remove(i);
                            list.remove(k - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        System.out.println(list);
        }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks to all who respond.